# Tracking number of attempts via Form API

Tags: 7, forms

I'd like to track the number of times a user has failed a form validation.

It doesn't necessarily matter if the end user has access to the variable, or even the ability to manipulate it client side, as the purpose is to provide additional help to the user by detecting when they might not be in trouble.

At this point I think I'm leaning towards adding a hidden field and incrementing that value, but I'm interested to know if there's a cleaner method that does prevent access and manipulation in my quest for knowledge :)

Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE**

As per tunic's advice below, I'm trying the `$form_state` route but this doesn't appear to be persisting. In my form validation function I have:

```
// Track the number of attempts.
if (!isset($form_state['mymodule']['attempts'])) {
  drupal_set_message('attempts not set');
  $form_state['mymodule']['attempts'] = 0;
}
$form_state['mymodule']['attempts']++;
drupal_set_message($form_state['mymodule']['attempts'] . ' attempts');
```

However repeatedly submitting a form with errors results in the following output each time:

```
attempts not set
1 attempts
```

**SOLUTION**

Having difficulty arguing with `$form_state` I instead went for the core flood module as suggested below, with the following code, in my validator:

```
function mymodule_booking_register_online_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (form_get_errors()) {
    form_set_error('', 'There was a problem registering your online account, please try again.');
    flood_register_event('mymodule_booking_register');
  }
}
```

And then to handle the result of this event, back in my form definition:

```
function mymodule_booking_register_online_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if (flood_is_allowed('mymodule_booking_register', 5, 3600)) {
    ...
  else {
    drupal_set_message('You have incorrectly entered your personal details too many times. Please call us on 12345678 to ask for your user code and then enter it in the form below.');
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Comment: Drupal 7, sorry should have specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using drupal 'floding mechanism' for login attempts ,so using flood_register_event() to have entry for custom event in flood table,but might be too overkill !

A better picture can be seen inside `user_login_authenticate_validate()` in user.module

Comment: This works great, and I can't see why it'd be overkill. Arguably it's not a "flood" but the functionality it provides is a perfect fit. Thanks!

Comment: the reason it might be overkill is it makes database query and the reason I used "flood" was just to address the functionality :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use a variable insider $form_state.

In validate function

```
if ($validation_failed) {
  $form_state['error_count']++
  $form_state['cache'] = TRUE;
}
```

Then, in your form function just check $form_state['error_count'].

$form_state will be persistent between page petitions while validation fails thanks to $form_state['cache'].

You can also check for errors using [form_get_errors()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7).

Comment: Good answer. Will not work for client-side validation and if user force-purge his browser, so it will only work for *honest* mistakes and *stupid* robots, but I think most cases are covered.

Comment: Usually editing code is a bad thing, but this time it was obvious typo. Note: correcting code typos in *questions* is different story.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work, please see my updated question.

Comment: I didn't add the $form_state['cache'] = TRUE line, this will make your form_stage persistent. Sorry.

Comment: Oh very interesting, maybe I'll try that as well, running into a few oddities with the flood route. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately `$form_state['cache']=TRUE` prevents the form from being modified at all, as it regurgitates the cached form, even alongside `$form_state['rebuild']=TRUE`.

Comment: form_set_error prevents form form rebuilding. You can use an after build function that is called even when form is retrieved froem cache.

So, as long as form_set_error prevents form rebuilding, if you need to modify form when a validate fails you can use that after_build function (depending on your task it may be difficult, as the form has been already constructed and you must know how to tweak the form element). Ahonther way is to avoid form_set_error, doing nothing in submit but passing a value on URL or SESSION.. but this is not canonical.